# What is the dimension of $\mathbb R[x] / \langle x^3-x\rangle$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$ ?

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

What is the dimension of  $\mathbb R[x] / \langle x^3-x\rangle$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$ ? Can someone please give some links , articles where I can study about polynomila rings and its quotient rings ?

Comment: Hint:Division Algorithm !

Answer (score 1):

Let $I = \langle x^3 - x\rangle$.  For $p \in \Bbb R[x]$, denote the element $p(x) + I$ by $p(t)$.

By the division algorithm, note that every element of $\Bbb R[x]/I$ can be written as $p(t)$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree *at most* $2$.  It follows that the set
$$
B = \{1,t,t^2\}
$$
is a spanning set of $\Bbb R[x]/I$.  Verify that $B$ is additionally linearly independent, so that it forms a basis.

---

**Illustrative example:**
$$
t^5 + t^4 = \\
(t^2+t)(t^3 - t) + t^2 + t = \\
(t^2 + t)\cdot(0) + t^2 + t =\\
t^2 + t = \\
1 \cdot t^2 + 1 \cdot t + 0 \cdot 1
$$
Intuitively, you can think of $\Bbb R[x]/I$ as $\Bbb R$ extended by a symbol $t$ that we've defined to satisfy $t^3 = t$.  Note that, since $x^3 - x$ has zeros in $\Bbb R$, this quotient ring is **not** a field (since it is not a domain, since it has zero divisors).